# Body overflow hidden problem in Internet Explorer 7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I need to apply the `overflow:hidden` to the body of a page with CSS, but is doesn't work in Internet Explorer 7. 
I've read about this topic but always with divs.
How can I make this work to Internet Explorer 7? I don't mind using jQuery.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

See here: http://www.artmov.com/dev/snippets/apply-overflow-x-overflow-y-to-body-in-ie7-ie6-84/:

> Applying `overflow-x:hidden` or `overflow-y:hidden;` to the body element of the document will not work. The `overflow-x:hidden` or `overflow-y:hidden` must be applied to the `html` element, not `body` element.